# How do I display full picture instead of cropped one in thumbnail?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a Wordpress online shop and I have this problem with thumbnails, because picture gets cropped to fit the square shape and the customer does not want that, he wants the picture to be displayed in full shape.

You can see the problem I am mentioning if you click the link below:

http://www.razgorsek.si/product-category/sedezne-garniture/

I couldn't find the CSS property that crops the thumbnail picture to square and I hope you can help me fix this problem.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Already uploaded pictures (i.e. their thumbnail version) are already cut to a square format (150x150 by default).

But in the backend > settings > media, in the first section "thumbnails", there is an option "cut thumbnails to exact size" (or similar) which is responsible for that behaviour. You can deactivate that.

Comment: I deactivated that but the thumbnails are still the same. Do I need to reupload images or something like that? Thank you for your comment otherwise!

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with my first paragraph: The existing thumbnails are already square image files - no way to change that. That setting is only valid for newly uploaded images.